# barcode scanner for OSX

Tags: macos

I am interested in buying a barcode scanner (for a one off to read ISBN numbers on books).
I have looked at some at the cheaper models on eBay, but they don't give much information.

I was wondering if anyone has experience with these. I want to use with my MacBook. Are any special drivers usually required?

Comment: I think that most barcodescanners present themself to your mac as an keyboard output. So when you scan something it wil act like you type it on your keyboard. This is how the scanner works at my work. I'm sorry but i don't have a name for the scanner.

Comment: Does it have to be a extra piece of hardware (like you described), or would scanning via your mobile phone (if you have one) be an option? It would be helpful if you could expand on what you are actually planning to do. Thanks!